# Using ]] in a GitHub flavored Wiki code tag inside a link

Tags: github, markdown

I'm looking to have the following:
`My String[Sub[Sub2]]`

But inside a link:
[[`My String[Sub[Sub2]]`|Page#tag]]

I have found that most of this can be achieved by:
`[[A string that does not have brackets in it.|Page#tag]]`

Any thoughts on how to do this? I've also tried a bit of terminating but have had no success:
`[[My String[Sub[Sub2\]\]|Page#tag]]` as this shows up as: `My String[Sub[Sub2\]\]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to encode the closing brackets as HTML entities and avoid having GitHub parse them to end the link. For right brackets you don't want to end links, use `&#93;`. (If you want to balance out your encoding by doing the left brackets too, replace 93 with 91.)

Comment: As a side note: I think this issue is related - https://github.com/github/gollum/issues/128